# change a part of pure text inside a td

Tags: jquery, text, replace, html-table

I didnt find an answer for this specific problem.

I have a dynamically generated table. Its a score table with names, countries, ranking and points. I want to replace pure text with an image.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Lindsey Vonn (usa)</td>
    <td>440</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>Lara Gut (sui)</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.</td>
    <td>Nicole Hosp (at)</td>
    <td>380</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The goal is to replace (usa) with a U.S. Flag (image).
Same for (sui) and so on...
I dont have ids or classes for table, td or tr.

Comment: I made an edit, this is the exact structure of the table. Sry. So i think i can't use "td:first". Im getting closer to a solution but its still not working. Thx for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hey man a simple solution and best solution ever but you have to change the flag images name as you have done with the name of people e.g for (usa) you will need to change flag image name with usa.jpg and similarly, for (sui)  you will need to change flag image name with sui.jpg :**

[Link To JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LBCVT/)

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each( function() { // this line is edited!
    var g = $(this).text();
    if(g!="") {
    var n = g.split("(");
        var t= n[0];
        var m = n[1];
        var s = m.replace(")", "");
        var img_code = "<img src='.html/"+s+".jpg'>"; // here you can change path. I have edited it for .html directory!
        $(this).html(t+img_code);
    }
});
```

and NOTE: **the images will not be shown in jsfiddle because they do not have images of usa.jpg or sui.jpg!**

Comment: Thx man! im even closer now :) i made 2 images sui.jpg and usa.jpg. Saved it to the .html directory but nothing happens? did i forgot something?

Comment: i have edited the code! see variable img_code their you can change the directory of images to any! In the case of .html directory `var img_code = "<img src='.html/"+s+".jpg'>";`

Comment: yes. i just made a test with your code on jsfiddle and put my http image path on it - et voilà! it just worked fine :) it looks like it just dont work localy (dont know why). Thanks alot. This is perfect!

Comment: by the way what is name of your domain! I wanted to see your website! if you like

Comment: hey man u changed the question above! the code i gave to you will also replace all other **td** in **tr** of **table**. So, for this purpose i edited the code above. ok!

Comment: Thank you very much! Its for a Web-App Project. Its still beta. U can take a look here: http://www.you-vs-tube.com/ski/
Im gonna use your code especially on the first box which is under construction :)

Comment: its a group project or you are single?

Comment: This solution works as requested, but I would be inclined to use regex instead of multiple string split and replace. I have updated my answer below for the new HTML (uses regex) including jsFiddle

Comment: hey good man! but the principle of programming that my teacher of computer science taught me is , **"Important is what you have done not how you have done"**. ;) I program according to this principle and i did what i can do for him!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib its a single project.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I was not saying that your solution did not work, merely that there is a better way - sorry if that offended you. The _principle_ your computer science teacher told you may work at school, but in the real world the way you solve a problem **is** important due to extensibility and reliability requirements. In this case, whilst a string replace answers the question, it is not the best way to solve the problem which the poster asked. Regex was made for this scenario and does very well here. You will see that our answers are very similar, albeit for the method of string replacement.

Comment: yeah man i know regular expressions are for this purpose! but the problem is i have never used regex and have no knowledge that how can we make regular expressions!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `regex` such as `\(([a-z]*)\)` and use the returned value to show a file with that name as the `img src`:

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\(([a-z]*)\)/, "<img src=\"$1.jpg\" />");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/macropus/EyEna/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
  var icons = {
    usa: '/path/to/usa.png',
    sui: '/path/to/sui.png',
    at:  '/path/to/at.png'    
  };

  // on DOM ready
  $(function() {
    // you need a way of selecting
    // that table and this selector
    // is dangerously generic
    var table = $('table'),
        markup = table.html(),
        image;

    $.each(icons, function(icon, path) {
      image = '<img src="' + path + '" alt="' + icon + '">';
      markup = markup.replace('(' + icon + ')', image); 
    });

    table.html(markup);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you. i can make a div with an id around the table so i can just call this specific table. What would the jquery code look like?

Comment: It would look the same except for the `var table = $('table'),` line. Change that to select your specific table. If the ID is on an element around the table it would need to be `var table = $('#yourId table'),` or you could just add the ID to the table - `var table = $('#yourTableId'),`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($("table tr td:first"),function(){
if($(this).html().indexOf("usa"))
{
$(this).html($(this).html().replace("<img src=''></img>)
}
...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript

```
var xx=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
for (var i=0;i<xx.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;i++)
document.write(xx.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML="<img src='anything.jpg' />");
```